# Finding the joint probability of dependent events

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

I am trying to probabilistically model a problem, a simple version of which is as below:

I have 100 participants for a lucky draw contest. Let us name them $a_{1}, a_{2},...a_{100}.$

Suppose that only the 10 participants namely $a_{1}, a_{2},...a_{10}$ are the possible winners and others are just participating for fun.

The lucky draw is as follows:

> *I will select each of the 100 participants independently with probability $p$ and if, in the selected set of people, there is only 1 participant from the set  $\mathcal{D}=\{a_{1}, a_{2},...a_{10}\}$,then that participant is a winner.*
>
> I will repeat this procedure (*which I call test*) $T$ times. and **I call my experiment to be a success if $a_{1}, a_{2}$ and $a_{3}$ are the winners after the $T$ tests**.

Let,

$L_{i}=\# \text { tests containing } i \text { and no other element of } \mathcal{D}, \text { for } i=a_{1}, \ldots, a_{10}$

$\mathbb{P}(\text { success })=\mathbb{P}\left(L_{1} \neq 0,L_{2} \neq 0, L_{3} \neq 0\right)$

How can I compute this probability of success? The problem I am facing is since  $L_{1},L_{2},L_{3}$ are not independent, I am not able to simplify the expression further?

Comment: Do you care if $a_4$ is one of the winners after $T$ tests as well as $A_1,a_2,a_3$?

Comment: No . I just care about a1,a2 and a3. You can think of they are my friends :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $a_1$ is "a winner" in a particular test if selected and the other nine are not with probability $p(1-p)^9$.

The same is true of $a_2$ and $a_3$ and these are mutually exclusive events for that particular test, so we can add their probabilities.

So over all $T$ tests:

- $P(L_1=0) = P(L_2=0) = P(L_3=0) = \left(1- p(1-p)^9\right)^T$
- $P(L_1=0, L_2=0) = P(L_2=0,L_3=0) = P(L_3=0,L_1=0) = \left(1- 2p(1-p)^9\right)^T$
- $P(L_1=0, L_2=0, L_3=0)=\left(1- 3p(1-p)^9\right)^T$

So by inclusion-exclusion $P(L_1=0 \text{ or } L_2=0 \text{ or } L_3=0) =  3\left(1- p(1-p)^9\right)^T - 3 \left(1- 2p(1-p)^9\right)^T + \left(1- 3p(1-p)^9\right)^T$

and thus $P(L_1\not =0, L_2\not =0, L_3\not =0) = 1- 3\left(1- p(1-p)^9\right)^T + 3 \left(1- 2p(1-p)^9\right)^T - \left(1- 3p(1-p)^9\right)^T$

This is an increasing function of $T$ but not of $p$. For example

- if $p=\frac1{100}$ and $T=100$ then this is about $0.2142$ as none of them are selected very often
- if $p=\frac1{10}$ and $T=100$ then this is about $0.9432$
- if $p=\frac1{2}$ and $T=100$ then this is about $0.00078$ as too many from $\mathcal D$ are selected too often

Comment: Just a typo: "and thus P(L1=1,L2=1,L3=1) "should be rewritten as P(L1 \neq 0,L2 \neq 0,L3 \neq 0) . right?

Comment: @JyotishRobin Yes, thank you